# How to apply function to only 1 column of dataframe but replicate the other column as many times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-processing

I have a dataframe which has 2 columns: Query & Category. I am applying data augmentation to the Query Column of my dataframe to make the query count as 797 under each category. I have the following code as of now, but this just makes the query as 797 for each category by repeating the rows until we reach the count of 797 under each category. What changes do I have to make to it to append augmented queries after the original ones under each category until we make 797 queries for each category:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('original_file.csv')
rep_val = 797
df2 = df2.groupby('Category').apply(lambda d: pd.concat(([d]*math.ceil(rep_val/d.shape[0]))).head(rep_val)).reset_index(drop = True)
df2.to_csv('result_file.csv, index = False')
```

The code I have for data augmentation is:

```
import nlpaug.augmenter.sentence as nas
aug = nas.ContextualWordEmbsForSentenceAug(model_path = 'xlnet-base-cased')
def run(doc):
    doc = aug.augment(doc)
    return doc
```

I made the function called run to do something like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Original_file_non797.csv')
query_to_be_augmented = df['Query']
query_to_be_augmented.apply(run)
```

But this does not achieve my final goal which is to keep the original queries and only then append the augmented queries until I have 797 under each category, and do all this while also making the category column count as 797 for each category.
An example for better understanding:

```
Suppose I need to make query count as 5 for each category
Sample Data Frame I have:

Query            Category

apple is good    fruit
mango is bad     fruit
hi how are you   greeting
good morning     greeting
hello there      greeting

After applying Augmentation, the resulting dataframe must be:

Query                Category

apple is good        fruit
mango is bad         fruit
apple is great       fruit
mango is horrible    fruit
apple good is        fruit
hi how are you       greeting
good morning         greeting
hello there          greeting
how are you doing    greeting
morning is good      greeting

As you can see, the original data remains, and augmented data is added to it until we have a count of 5 for each category.
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with an example of my own (since you don't provide a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) one):

```py
import random
import pandas as pd

def run():
    """Fake helper function.

    Returns:
        3 letters random string.
    """
    return "".join(random.choices("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", k=3))


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Query": ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno"],
        "Category": ["cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2"],
    }
)
```

```
print(df)
# Output
  Query Category
0   abc     cat1
1   def     cat1
2   ghi     cat2
3   jkl     cat2
4   mno     cat2
```

```py
TARGET = 5  # Up to 5 rows per category

# Add new rows
for cat, count in df["Category"].value_counts().to_dict().items():
    df = pd.concat(
        [df]
        + [
            pd.DataFrame({"Query": [run()], "Category": [cat]})
            for _ in range(TARGET - count)
        ]
    )

# Cleanup
df = df.sort_values(by=["Category"]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
print(df)
# Output
  Query Category
0   abc     cat1
1   def     cat1
2   iyz     cat1
3   weh     cat1
4   bge     cat1
5   ghi     cat2
6   jkl     cat2
7   mno     cat2
8   auy     cat2
9   wdu     cat2
```